# How to handle this scenario in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a multi-tenant app with asp.net mvc. I have to identify tenant for each request so i have created a class below:

```
public class TenantProvider
    {
        public static Tenant Tenant
        {
            get
            {
                Tenant tenant = HttpContext.Current.Items["Tenant"] as Tenant;

                if (tenant == null)
                {
                    var tenantUsername = HelperUtility.GetCurrentRequestHost();
                    //The below line of code is my problem
                    TenantRepository tenantRepository = new TenantRepository(new AppointContext());
                    tenant = tenantRepository.GetByUsername(tenantUsername);
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Tenant", tenant);
                }

                return tenant;
            }
        }
    }
```

This class static property returning the Tenant for current request. It will first check for the Tenant in cache, if not found than if will get the Tenant from the database, initialize the cache and return the Tenant.

For getting Tenant form the database i am creating a TenantRepository instance. TenantRepository has a dependency over database context, which i am passing it while creating its instance.

Now when i have to do other database operation on current Tenant than i have to create a new Repository instance at some other place and have to pass new Context, so the actual context with which i have extracted the Tenant and the new Context differ which i think may create the problem.

So my question is how can i handle this scenario, so that same context instance will be used ??

Comment: Why not storing the tenant in a claim?

Comment: @Swell will you please elaborate your suggestion with some link or sample code??

Comment: Here is a mini crash course on claims http://vimeo.com/43549130 this is a great video from Dominick Baier. You should also have a look at this project https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot from Brock Allen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is the Unit of Work design pattern. From Martin Fowler:

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

ref: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html

This pattern allows you to enroll multiple transactions into a single context. This is a very common pattern, and here is one possible implementation. First, create a Unit of Work object which will hold a reference to your central context, and which will initialize your repositories with that context (this implementation uses the Entity Framework):

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    internal EntitiesContext _context = new EntitiesContext ();
    private ITenantRepository _tenantRepository;
    private IOtherRepository _otherRepository;

    public ITenantRepository TenantRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tenantRepository== null)
            {
                _tenantRepository= new TenantRepository(_context);
            }
            return _tenantRepository;
        }
    }

    public IOtherRepository OtherRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_otherRepository== null)
            {
                _otherRepository= new OtherRepository(_context);
            }
            return _otherRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Note that if you use any repository with this pattern, they will all use the same context.

Your controller should either initializing the Unit of of Work, or even better, have it injected into its constructor:

```
    public TenantController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _tenantRepository = unitOfWork.TenantRepository;
        _otherRepository = unitOfWork.OtherRepository;
    }
```

If you need to use the UnitOfWork to another layer, you would typically pass it as an argument to another object's constructor:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    TenantProvider provider = new TenantProvider(_unitOfWork);
    _otherRepository.DoWork();
    _unitOfWork.Save();
 }
```

Now your `TenantProvider` can do some work with its respective repository, but the Unit of Work's `OtherRepository` can also do some work using the same context.

Comment: thanks for your answer and its really helpful +1, i want to know why you use interfaces like ITenantRepository and so on in your sample code. Actually i know the theory of interface (contract b/w class and all) but i really never understand the real use of it means i never feel something like `yes here is the requirement of an interface`. So will you please explain me the real use of interfaces in your sample code ??

Comment: Code to an interface, not to an implementation. In the code above, my controller doesn't know anything about how the repository persists its data. While my example uses the Entity Framework, because it is behind an interface, I could in theory swap out my repository with one that saves to an XML doc, MySQL, a text file... Decoupling your code ensures your code is more maintainable and resilient to change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@ChrisHardie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21677583/642579), I want to add some MVC specifics: I think it is a very good practice to inject the Unit of Work into the controllers. In order to do so, you can create a custom ControllerFactory that is derived from [DefaultControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and is registered at application startup:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType) 
    {
        // Analyze whether instance of controllerType should be created directly or 
        // whether the Unit of Work should be injected
        if (needsUnitOfWork)
            return (IController)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, unitOfWork);
        else
            return (IController)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

In order to discern between controllers that need a Unit of Work and those that do not, you could use reflection (custom attributes or inspecting constructor arguments). Maybe you can also assume that each controller needs a Unit of Work for the moment.

If you are already using an Inversion of Control container, it can support you in creating the instances (IoC containers are usually plugged in in a ControllerFactory in MVC). If not, you might consider to start using one.

You can register the ControllerFactory like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
       // ...
       RegisterCustomControllerFactory ();
       // ...
    }

    private void RegisterCustomControllerFactory ()
    {
        IControllerFactory factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
    }
}
```

As this answers builds upon the extension points for Dependency Injection in MVC, this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618491) might help.